# How can I create a Half Circle without Spacing in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a half Circle at the bottom. But theres some space which I cant delete.
// Flutter

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBBTd.png)

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this view using ArcView [link](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter). See attached image

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Arc(
                arcType: ArcType.CONVEX,
                edge: Edge.TOP,
                height: 70.0,
                clipShadows: [ClipShadow(color: Colors.black)],
                child: new Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: Colors.lime,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Or create a custom clipper

```
class CustomHalfCircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Use Above class as shown below

```
new ClipPath(
          clipper: new CustomHalfCircleClipper(),
          child: new Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

why not going the easy way
something like this

```dart
Container(
    height: 30,
    width: 50,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Simple solution, Thank you